# Outlook Send/Recieve gives 0X8004010F 'Cant find Object' with Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007

When trying to Send/Recieve Outlook throws 0X8004010F 'Cant find Object', the account is an Exchange account, Exchange 2007.
I tried stopping MSExchangeFDS, deleting OAB, Updating OAB and restarting MSExchangeFDS.

Please advice.

Comment: Is your OAB published in public folders, using web based distribution or both? If in public folders, is the public folder database mounted? Also, does this happen across multiple versions of Outlook, or only specific ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with certificates. They can be very tricky if you do not understand them. I am going to cut and past my internal document I created for me, however, if you are not highly technical, I suggest that you spend the $260 and have Microsoft walk you through it.

This is a guide from beginning to end, and is for self-signed certificates.
If you have a paid certificate from a certificate authority, you can bypass steps 1, and 7-11.

How to do a self-signed certificate in Exchange 2007 on Server 2003

1. Install Certificate Services in Add/Remove Programs>Add/Remove Windows Components. Install it as an Enterprise Root CA.
2. In the Exchange Management Shell run the following command: Get-ExchangeCertificate and take note of the thumbprints.
3. Run the following command:
   •   New-ExchangeCertificate -DomainName yourservername.yourdomain.com, yourservername,  autodiscover.yourdomain.com, mail.yourdomain.com -FriendlyName "Exchange SAN Certificate"  -GenerateRequest:$True -Keysize 1024 -path c:\cert1.txt -privatekeyExportable:$true -subjectName  "c=us, o=Exchange Server, CN=yourdomain.com"  (It is important to add all the common names, internal and external,  as in the example above there are 4...replace the yourservername and your domain as appropriate)
4. Run the following command in a normal DOS box from the same directory as the cert1.txt file above:  certreq -submit -attrib "CertificateTemplate: WebServer" cert1.txt (you will be asked to give it a name c:\temp\cert.cer, for example)
   •   If you get an error message about it not being trusted, restart the Certificate Services and try again.
5. In the Exchange Management Shell run the following command: Import-ExchangeCertificate –path c:\temp\cert.cer (or whatever path and name you used) and note which thumbprint has been added when you run Get-ExchangeCertificate again. If you are unsure, re-run the  Import-ExchangeCertificate –path c:\temp\cert.cer command, and it will tell you explicitly what thumbprint it is. You cannot just view the certificate’s properties to get this information.
6. In the Exchange Management Shell run the following command: Enable-ExchangeCertificate -Services iis,pop,smtp,imap . It will ask you for a thumbprint. Cut and paste the new thumbprint and hit enter.
7. Open the MMC and add the certificates snap-in for the Computer account. Import the c:\temp\cert.cer to the “Personal” store so it shows in the next step.
8. In IIS 6, go to the web site that has OWA, usually the Default Web Site. Go to Properties>Directory Security>Server Certificate and remove the current certificate.
9. In IIS 6, go to the web site that has OWA, usually the Default Web Site. Go to Properties>Directory Security>Server Certificate and select and install the new c:\temp\cert1.cer certificate.
10. On the user’s computer, open the MMC and add the certificates snap-in for the Computer account. Import the c:\temp\cert.cer to the “Trusted Root Certification Authorities” store.
11. Go to your OWA site and when you get the certificate error, import the certificate. Click on any level of the hierarchy that shows a red error and import it there. This should allow you to go to the OWA site directly, with no certificate error.

•   If you still have problems, it may be necessary to follow the following document: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940726
•   You can check your URLs with the following commands:
o   Get-ClientAccessServer |fl
o   Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory |fl
o   Get-OABVirtualDirectory |fl
o   Get-UMVirtualDirectory |fl